# Getting fullcalendar events from handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

I need to add events to the jquery fullcalendar from the handler.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var events_ = null;
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Handler.ashx",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (eventString) {
                events_ = JSON.stringify(eventString);
            },
            Error: function (err) {
                alert("Error while getting events");
            }
        });

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            theme: true,
            editable: true,
            events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1)
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)
            }
           ]
        });
    });
```

In handler, I'm building a json object with event properties such as id, title, start.

```
EventEntity eventEntity = new EventEntity();
eventEntity.id = "1111";
eventEntity.title = "MyTitle";
eventEntity.start = DateTime.Now; 
string eventString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventEntity); // using NewtonSoft.Json
context.Response.Write(eventString);
```

How can I add events got from handler to calendar along with existing events.

Comment: You can use `eventSources` to set source from multiple locations.